# How to add an assignee to an issue without giving them access rights to the repository?

Tags: github, issue-tracking

I want to assign issues to users in my github repository, but don't give them access rights.

Each user I want to be able to assign issues to has a fork of the repository.

Is there a way to do this, without mentioning (`@`) them for each issue?